# Promise after Promise after Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I wanted to fetch something from my database (through axios) like this [in order]:

1. Questions
2. Choices
3. Answers

I can get it with this:

```
// Get Questions
    axios.get(url_here)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            // Save Questions...
            // Get Choices
            axios.get(url_here)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    // Save Choices...
                    // Get Answers
                    axios.get(url_here)
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res.status === 200) {
                            // Save Answers
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

But just by the looks of this, this code is bound to fail one way or another.

If I do something like this:

```
// Get Questions
axios.get(url_here)
.then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        // Save Questions...
    }
})

// Get Choices
axios.get(url_here)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            // Save Choices...
        }
})
    
// Get Answers
axios.get(url_here)
.then(res => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        // Save Answers
    }
})
```

`Get Choices` can be called regardless if `Get Questions` is successful or not.
How can I do it if I want `Get Choices` to "wait and listen" if `Get Questions` is successful in its request?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"this code is bound to fail one way or another"* - In what way did the code fail?  If you want to wait until an asynchronous operation completes before performing the next operation then the `.then()` callback is exactly where you'd put that next operation.  You could perhaps clean it up by using `await` instead of chaining the promises, but the resulting logic is the same.  So what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @David Oh I'm sorry. For me it really looks like a spaghetti code (with nested axios calls) and I'm kinda scared just by looking at it. Anyhow, someone told me in the past that I can only use either `await` or `.then` since I cannot mix one with the other (axios uses `.then`). How can I execute my code with `await` but still use axios?

Comment: You wouldn't need `.then()` if you use `await`.  Everything that happens after it is in an implicit `.then()`.  You'd just do something like `let res = await axios.get(url_here);` and then you'd have the result of the `.get()` call in `res`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is use async await.

```
const getQuestions = await axios.get(url);
if(getQuestions){
 const getchoices = await axios.get(url);
}
```

remember await can only be used in an async function

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at `Promise.all()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Or learn about `async` `await`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Can I use `async` and `.then` at the same time? Someone told me in the past I can't mix one with the other.

Comment: You could but you don't want to.